# Insert a row of elements into a multi-dimensional array based on index

Tags: javascript

Insert a row of elements into a multi-dimensional array based on index

For Example:

```
MultiArray = new Array(5);

MultiArray [0] = new Array(2);

MultiArray [0][0] = "Tom";

MultiArray [0][1] = "scientist";


MultiArray [1] = new Array(3);

MultiArray [1][0] = "Beryl";

MultiArray [1][1] = "engineer";

MultiArray [1][2] = "Doctor";

MultiArray [2] = new Array(2);

MultiArray [2][0] = "Ann";

MultiArray [2][1] = "surgeon";

MultiArray [3] = new Array(2);

MultiArray [3][0] = "Bill";

MultiArray [3][1] = "taxman";

MultiArray [4] = new Array(2);

MultiArray [4][0] = "Myrtal";

MultiArray [4][1] = "bank robber";

MultiArray.splice(1,0, new Array(2){"two","one"});
```

The last line in my code didn't work. I am not sure if the rest of the code is right neither.

Now can anyone please let me know whether I can insert a row of elements somewhere in between and move the remaining elements one index down?

Comment: java != javascript. I removed the java tag.

Comment: @Sushil why? It's absolutely ok to write `new Array(10)`

Comment: @Sushil: No, its not :). Go ahead and try:
`var a = new Array(10);
console.log(a.join("wat"));`

Comment: `MultiArray.splice(1,0, MultiArray.splice(2,1) );`

Is this allowed? I tried this because the splice() returns a row of array but its not working.

Comment: Raghul, perhaps splice does not what you think it does? Check the [splice doc on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to make sure. I wrote **[an example](http://jsfiddle.net/SDGez/1/)** from your code and it works exactly like it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
MultiArray.splice(1,0, ["two","one"]);
```

Answer (score 4):

You accidently wrote `new Array{}` which is wrong - your command should be either:

```
MultiArray.splice(1,0, new Array(2)("two","one")); // no curled brackets!!
```

or even better

```
MultiArray.splice(1,0, ["two","one"]);
```

Altogether, in javascript the `new Array()` notation should be avoided (js automatically controls the dimension of it's arrays, no need to preallocate or declare it). Instead you can write:

```
MultiArray = [];
```

So, you can directly write:

```
MultiArray = [[ "Tom","scientist"],["Beryl","engineer","Doctor"],
              ["Ann","surgeon"],["Bill","taxman"],["Myrtal","bank robber"]];

MultiArray.splice(1,0, ["two","one"]);
```